# User's date countdown. how to create a code which will allow user insert his own date

Tags: android, countdown

I want to develop an app which will count down to a specific date that the user will insert. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file, use the datepicker widget to enable user to enter the date. Store the date entered by user into sharedpreferences. Whenever the user opens the app again, this date is picked up from shared preferences and then do the date difference calculation. Implement a countdowntimer and display the countdown.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Just search for how to do individual parts of it and put it in code. It's not too difficult. If this answer was helpful mark it as answered

Comment: You will find all the resources on youtube videos. So it will be easy to implement